# Where can I ask for recommendations for good and tested online training websites for ASP.NET?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to know if users know good and tested online training websites for the ASP.NET. I know this question does not fit Stack Overflow.

Can you guide me where to ask this? Is there any Stack Exchange Q&A where this would be appropriate?

Comment: Have you looked at.. http://asp.net ? Tons of tutorials :P

Comment: Yes I did but I want online training course with a live instructor.

Comment: there isnt a site for that question

Comment: Consult your local community college.

Comment: If there is no stack site to answer this, we can close with question.

Comment: @Cody, you misspelled "pub".

Comment: I presume you've seen the existing (closed) questions? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/62251/1768779 The definitive answer does seem to be the official resources.

Answer (score 10):

There currently isn't a site within the network that supports such questions I'm afraid. Your best bet would be a topic-related chatroom, if the users there welcome such recommendation requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is ton of books on ASP.NET. e.g. [Beginning ASP.NET 4: in C# and VB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470502215)

Also some good websites, you can start with http://www.asp.net/get-started

I personally prefer a book since authors usually do some good job picking the important stuff out of everything that official docs have to offer.

Read some book fast and then search for solution to particular problems that you encounter.

No training will cover all real world situations, however book at least tries to cover most of tools available.

In .NET there are also some good resources to prepare for certifications but I did not have a change to read those.