# How to find out if a question might lead to lengthy discussions instead of answers

Tags: discussion, downvotes, scope

Please be kind; I yet try to understand the culture of this site.

I have been coding for 40 years now. I don't think anybody can say I am avoiding my own solutions, but my experience tells to avoid to reinvent the wheel. With many solutions I did in the past, I later found out that there was already an existing solution. So I always first search for an existing solution before I do something new. I think that, often, it is a problem somebody else already had; let's look at their solutions, if there is one.

This way, I was able to learn very much and also be very productive, as well as  being able to contribute really new stuff in the past.

Now I struggle to formulate good questions because it seems to me that this site only caters those being stuck inside their code, and not such much to those thinking before they code.

Am I right? I like to give advice very much, and I seem to have been able to help. My problem seems to be that getting advice myself seems to be too a high level, or am I wrong?

What, if I don't find anything by searching (and I am also quite good in that, e.g. recently I found a non-commercial TWiki to Confluence-Converter, you can try that by yourself) about concepts, known strategies, techniques. 
So there is information left only in peoples heads, people that likely use stackoverflow. The question was for examples of solutions for a specific kind of problem. (providing services of commandline-interface-tools as web-application)

The hope was, that anybody might provide a link to the source code of such an example. Earlier the question was for ideas how to solve that kind of problem, I accepted, that that might be to broad.

After reading the comments the summary for me is, you need some experience, with questions, discussion, emotionalities and the close-vote-strategy of experienced users, to know, how questions might be asked and how not.

Comment: _"this forum only caters to those being stuck inside their code and not such much..."_ Related: [Are code troubleshooting questions really what we want to encourage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107116) | [Stack Overflow has too many too localised new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105365)

Comment: Narrow aspects of design are OK, outsourced product research is not:)

Comment: As far as your latest question being off-topic is concerned, you might be interested in reading [Why won't Stack Exchange reconsider the “recommend or find a tool” off-topic tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319285/6214222). There are also good answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/6214222)

Comment: @Keiwan I understand, asking for a tool, language or even a complete solution is quite lame and possibly provoking unnecessary controversy. But I asked specifically for examples of a class of problems, to get ideas of an elegant solution. That is no tool, here I thought of source code I have to analyse and understand.

Comment: a few days ago, somebody asked about having to store billions of objects inside a Java VM. I thought it very interesting to think and discuss such an possibly "off topic" question, even when some participants got quite strange in their comments.

Comment: But that still falls under the same close reason, which includes *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool (...) or other off-site resource (...)"*. The reasons why it's off-topic for SO are the same as to why tool requests are off-topic. It's not about what you intend to do with the answer (whether you just want a ready solution or whether you want some example reference of how something can be done). It's about the types of answers that these questions attract, which most of the time are of low quality. Relaxing these rules doesn't scale well, especially with the size of SO.

Comment: @Keiwan I start to understand, but not being able to ask, because of a difficult view on the world, that my colleagues seem to have, makes it a bit difficult to accept this. Anyway we seem to prefer to solve the problem at hand to the class of problems we experience in our career. That makes SO a kind of crossword puzzle.

Comment: Thank you very much. That made things clearer. I tend to delete the question, since it's obviously a duplicate.

Comment: Relevant, maybe? [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Comment: @TiesonT. I am not comfortable with the impression, that my question is reduced to the question whether stackoverflow was a forum or not. I regret having used that word now. My question sought direct answers: just pointers to a piece of sourcecode or a website, I was not able to find or just information from people more experienced in that matter than me. As I understand, the potential that this question might lead to longer discussion and therefore to something which was more suitable on a forum was the cause for the "off topic" - judgement.

Comment: My intention was more to draw your attention to answers like https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/169018, from that question, which elaborates on @Oded's answer here or Keiwan's comment earlier. I would assume from the various comments, though, that you get that the simple answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: I don't think there is a service yet with the idea of a discussion forum without being horrible like a discussion forum. Stack Overflow is a big lure because plenty of intelligent people hang out there answering questions, but that is a trap; those people are there to answer questions, they're not necessarily there to engage in open discussion. What you're looking for is a venue where people congregate that *are* looking for open discussion. If you find it and it is actually not a toxic environment, do tell!

Answer (score 33):

> Doesn't Stack Overflow also want to be a forum, where people can advice on, give pointers or discuss such a topic?

It does not. The Q&A part of the site is exactly about that: questions and answers. Not discussions, advice and pointers.

Practical questions which can be objectively answered.

That's the forte of the Q&A engine - we tried "anything goes" a few times and *it does not work*. People who answer stop answering and go away - the site becomes a ghost town, which *is not good for anyone*.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I think my intention were not to provide answers. I wanted information (answers) about a kind of problems, without immediately starting to code. That without comment a kind of "off topic" police motions for closing, I find quite shocking. There was no discussion, the question got discredited without comment and in my opinion without good cause. Do you use bots?

Comment: No bots @aschoerk only fanatic close voters like me ...

Comment: @rene that's comforting. So you are keeping SO clean. I will remove the question, four votes to close convinced me. There seems to be anyway nobody who knows foreign code anymore, at least at SO. ... I am quite frustrated, because looking at the other questions of mine, these I can delete as well. SO seems more to be a "reputation by answer trivial questions collection machine", than anyhow helpful for experienced coders.

Comment: @aschoerk Don't forget to check other sites in the SE network. Maybe Software Engineering.SE is better suited for your type of questions? Check their help center though before running off to that place. They are even more furious in keeping stuff out they don't feel are in scope.

Comment: @rene thank you, as I know so called software engineers, they might not like to look too deep into source code ;-) . So my questions might not fit there either. But thank you. Perhaps searchcode.com is the best option.

Comment: @aschoerk that question looks fine to me, may could have a simple maven/surefire xml file  (IIRC it works with xml files) to illustrate your use case. Maybe not many users run into issues with their test where they need to know the PID.  Also, 29 views in 25 days. It is not a particular high-viewed question. Sometimes it takes years to get an [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A578411+is%3Aa+score%3A0)

Comment: @rene Thank you very much. That made things clearer. I tend to delete the question, since it's obviously a duplicate. And I am not as frustrated with SO as I sounded. In contrary I profited in the past very much. Just not by questions I myself formulated.

Comment: I see that you do not have the "not a robot" badge, @rene. Why should we believe that you are not, in fact, a bot?

Comment: One thing I might point out: Stack Overflow is not the complete solution format for all forms of beneficial dialogue. It has no pretensions of being such. It has a narrow and focused goal which it usually delivers on very well. I do not recall any moderator or very high-reputation user ever suggesting that the StackExchange umbrella is the only forum that should ever exist or that users should ever visit.

Comment: 'as I know so called software engineers, they might not like to look too deep into source code'.they have to.   Getting software to work IS engineering.  That encompasses writing source code, compiling, linking and many cycles of debugging/testing before verification and, (maybe), delivery, (whether to a real customer or a prof/TA).  Software development IS engineering, and those who enter this field while only thinking of 'writing code' are in for a huge disappointment.  It is really annoying when OP's post 'My code compiles without error but STILL does not work!' - they don't get it :(

Comment: @MartinJames you are right, perhaps I yet have the picture of the SE of the 80's in mind, I learned at the university of.